# SQL How to filter changes in columns

Tags: sql

My problem is the following:

```
ID   Value   Date
---------------------------------
ID1    1     2014.03.03
ID2    1     2014.03.04    
ID1    2     2014.03.04  
ID3    1     2014.03.04  
ID2    1     2014.03.05  
ID2    1     2014.03.05   
ID1    2     2014.03.05    
ID1    2     2014.03.05
ID1    2     2014.03.05
ID1    1     2014.03.05
ID1    3     2014.03.05
```

And I would like the following output:

```
ID   Value   Date
---------------------------------
ID1    1     2014.03.03    
ID1    2     2014.03.04  
ID3    1     2014.03.04  
ID2    1     2014.03.05 
ID1    1     2014.03.05  
ID1    3     2014.03.05
```

So if ID1's value is 1 I'd like to get only once (the date doesn't matter it could be the newest or the oldest). But if the value changes (even to an earlier value) I'd like to write it to the output.
How can I do that?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Btw: there is no column `ID1` in your example, only `id`, `value` and `date` (all three being horrible names btw)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, i dont think that DBMS name have some significance here. and here why ID1 and value 1 is repeated i dont understand?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: yes, the DBMS *is* important. Not all DBMS offer the same level of features. My solution will not work with e.g. the limited functionality of MySQL

Comment: Thanks for your comments! I'm using MySQL. Yeah the column names are horrible, this is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't state your DBMS so this is ANSI SQL.

Something like this might do:

```
select id, value, date
from (
   select id, value, date, 
          lag(value) over (order by id, date) as prev_value
   from the_table
) t
where value <> prev_value
order by id, value;
```

It selects all rows where the value in the column `value` (btw: a horrible name for a column) is different than the value of that column in the previous row.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd: they are called "window functions" in the SQL standard.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use DISTINCT.

```
Select distinct ID, Value, Date From YOUR_TABLE
```

So for Tuples if there are data having Same values for all the 3 columns it will show only one instance of the data. But if one of the columns has a different data it will consider it as different from previous and kepp it in the output.

Comment: Saw that, so I removed my comment. :)